# My validation all came in one

Tags: java, android, validation, passwords

I'm having some problem on validation. How to change my coding so that the validation can come one at a time. I'm watching to many tutorial and here the result. I want my validation came one by one. So how it should be? Thanks in advance.

```
  private void RegisterAccount(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, String confirmpass)
{
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname))
    {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your first name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
    {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your last name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
    {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your valid email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmpass)) {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Please write your password again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (password != confirmpass)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else
    {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Creating New Account");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we are creating account for you.");
        loadingBar.show();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "You have successfully signed up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Signup.this, MainActivity.class);
                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Error occured, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use else -if instead of if.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname))
{
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your first name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
{
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your last name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
{
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your valid email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
{
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter your password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmpass)) {
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Please write your password again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if (password != confirmpass)
{
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Omaigod! It works! Thanks! But... the button does not work as usual :(

Comment: by use of 'else if' it always execute only one statement and by use of 'if' it checks all  statments utill it gets true statement.

Comment: Password same as confirmation password, but the validation error pop out, why I cant go to next interface?

Comment: you should check (!password.equals(confirmpass)) instead of (password != confirmpass.

Comment: Omg! It works! Thanks you so much sir. Can I ask you some question sir?

Comment: else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Error occured, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

Comment: this validation occur when I put very short password, why? bcause i didnt put any specification for password

Comment: Can you show me your code? I can not understand your question.

Comment: i cant copy the code sir, bcause it long coding. can I have your email sir? :)

Comment: Yes, My email id is shahharsh1910@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean validateName() {
    if (inputName_reg.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ) {
        inputLayoutName_reg.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
        requestFocus(inputName_reg);
        return false;
    } else{
        inputLayoutName_reg.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

You need to use "else If" and not just "if" that way the code works faster. use booleans to validate, they are more dynamic. I hope I have helped you, Regards !!

Comment: Thanks! How bout the validation for email precisely? Which means, if user insert addajalil for her email address without "@", it should show an error.

Comment: you can specify the type of input in this case is: android:inputType="textEmailAddress"   https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style

Comment: nice to help you!